# Java RMI threads on client-side are executing sequentially or concurrently when calling the same remote object?

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server, rmi, client-side

I am having trouble understanding a specific aspect of java RMI.

There's a client that creates N threads that do a lookup on the RMIregistry:

```
    Registry rmiRegistry;
    try {
        rmiRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(8585);
    IGestoreSportello igs = (IGestoreSportello)rmiRegistry.lookup("gestoresportelli");
    ExecutorService s = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for(int i = 0; i < T; i++){
        s.execute(new threadRunner(igs));
    }
```

Where "gestoresportelli" was previously registered as a service in the Server.

So, as far as my understanding goes, the clients are given all the same reference to the SAME object.

What I am asking here is, when I call a method on this object, is it the CLIENT executing the server's code?

Or is it the server that sequentially calls methods on that object?

---

So supposing we have:

thread1, thread2, thread3. They all call the same method on the same remote object which was registered on the server.

Do they call it sequentially:

```
Thread1->RemoteObjectReference.doSomething();
wait thread 1 to finish...
Thread2->RemoteObjectReference.doSomething();
wait thread 2 to finish...
Thread3->RemoteObjectReference.doSomething();
```

OR concurrently:

```
Thread1->RemoteObjectReference.doSomething();
Thread2->RemoteObjectReference.doSomething();
Thread3->RemoteObjectReference.doSomething();
```

all at the same time, even tho that's the same remote object?

I hope I was clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: I have found that my question is similar to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300145/race-condition-in-rmi-java-2-client-1-server

Answer (score 1):

> What I am asking here is, when I call a method on this object, is it the CLIENT executing the server's code?

No.

> Or is it the server that sequentially calls methods on that object?

It is the server, but sequentiality isn't defined.

> Do they call it sequentially

It isn't defined.

> OR concurrently:

It isn't defined.

To put that more strongly, the RMI specification states specifically that there are no guarantees about associations between client threads and server threads.

All you can deduce from that is that you cannot assume it is single-threaded.

Comment: So if I have 30threads invoking the same method on a remote object, this method has a sleep of 5 seconds... Does it take 30*5seconds or we are around the 5seconds time?

Comment: What part of "it isn't defined" don't you understand?

Comment: Did a test program and ran it many times it always takes 5 seconds. I found this explanation here: http://www.comp.lancs.ac.uk/~weerasin/csc253/tutorials/week7.html

"Therefore, if you make remote calls from separate clients (executing in different JVMs) each call will run in a separate thread. However, if you make concurrent calls from the same client (this can be acheived by using client-side threading, see later) then it is possible these calls will execute on the same server thread."

Anyway, thank you.

Comment: I am citing the RMI Specification. You can't cite non-normative references in refutation of that. The one you have cited contradicts itself. The behaviour you're asking about is deliberately and explicitly not specified. Period. Whatever behaviour you may have observed is the behaviour of that  implementation. It is free to change overnight.

Comment: I am not refusing anything. I am just trying to understand a particulare behaviour of something I am currently studying. Probably I will have to study it better for a deeper understanding. 
The behaviour I have observed is compatible with sources I have found online, one of those I have provided in the previous answer. 
I am not trying to prove anything here. Just thought there was a simple answer to what seemed to be a simple question (Yes, I got "it's not defined"). As you said I have to provide a RMI specification and I'll make sure to study from there from now on.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: To beat the dead horse a bit more, if you only wanted an experimental result I don't see why you even posted the question. You could have just done the experiment. I naturally assumed you wanted an answer per specification. And you need to understand that a completely single-threaded RMI implementation would be compliant with the specification. Not much use, but compliant. Indeed, in the early days there were plenty of people asserting on the Internet that it *was* single-threaded. You just cannot rely on arbitrary third-party sources.